# How to set switch on/off state iOS?

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I tried to set a switch to on state using `[self.switchAutoPlay setOn:YES]`. But It's not working. Here what I've done,

**In interface**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switchAutoPlay;
```

**In implementation**

```
[[self switchAutoPlay] setOn:YES];
```

Let me know a way to make this work.

Comment: Did you connect your outlet?

Comment: Have you hooked the IBOutlet up correctly? `self.switchAutoPlay.on = YES;` should work. Also check that self.switchAutoPlay is not `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initially check , Did you connect your outlet of `UISwitch`

in your `viewdidload`

```
 switchAutoPlay.isOn --> is for on 

!switchAutoPlay.isOn --> is for off
```

for method

```
[switchAutoPlay addTarget: self action: @selector(flip:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

for method of

```
 - (IBAction)flip:(id)sender{

if([sender isOn]){
    NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
} else{
    NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
}

}
```

**Choice-2**

UISwitch,  seen in the developper API, the task `setOn: animated:` should do the trick.

```
- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated
```

So to set the switch ON in your program, you would use:

**Objective-C**

```
[switchAutoPlay setOn:YES animated:YES];
```